# handleSignInResult returns false

Tags: android, google-signin

I had an old android project(about 3 months I had not touched it). Now that I am rebuilding the project, google signin is not working. I realize that

```
result.isSuccess()
```

is returning false and

```
result.getStatus().getStatusCode()
```

is returning 10.

my codes:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

and

```
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        assert acct != null;
        googleSigninToken = acct.getIdToken();
        Toast.makeText(this, googleSigninToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enteredEmail = acct.getEmail();
        signInGoogle(googleSigninToken);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "no success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and in my `signInGoogle` function, i pass the google signin token to server and the rest is not my concern.

Where is the problem?
if that matters I have the following in gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
```

Comment: Is your application is registered at `Firebase Console` ?

Comment: @AdityaSonel yes of course, the project was working properly 3 months ago. can it be because I am using debug version and not registered one?